# How to define the Charts in the script?

Tags: vue.js, chart.js

I'm new working on the vue js and I want to make a chart in the app and first i will install the charts in the directory using the command

```
npm install chart.js --save
```

and the code for creating the chart is

```
 <template>
   <canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
</template>

<script>
 var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
 var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
   type: 'bar',
   data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
        label: '# of Votes',
        data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
        backgroundColor: [
            'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
            'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
            'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
            'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
            'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
            'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
        ],
        borderColor: [
            'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
            'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
            'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
            'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
            'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
            'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
        ],
        borderWidth: 1
    }]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
        yAxes: [{
            ticks: {
                beginAtZero:true
            }
        }]
      }
   }
 });
 </script>
```

There is an error of the `Chart is not defined`. How will I solve this problem to create a chart.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler complains about `Chart` being not defined, because it does not know that it should load `Chart` from the `chart.js` package. Per [the integration documentation](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/getting-started/integration.html) you can simply put `import Chart from 'chart.js'` at the top of your script. You may need to include the `moment` package as well.

Comment: if i am importing that line then it would give me the error of the `Cannot read property 'length' of null` ?? why this error is geting @sumurai8

Comment: This is because there is some part of the code in the form of `x.length` where `x` is set to `null`. Figure out which line of code is the source of the error and you will get some idea as to how to fix it.